# How do I change the background color of the navbar in Ionic 2?

Tags: cordova, mobile, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to change the navbar background color in Ionic 2.  I have tried many things, like class="bar bar-stable" etc

Right now my code looks like this:

```
<ion-navbar  *navbar>
```

So the background is currently grey (default)

Answer (score 9):

from ionic 2 you can add custom style in your src/theme/variables.scss file

[image]

And then add the class where you want

[image]

[image]

Now see the result

[image]

Reference : [Theming your Ionic App](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/theming-your-app/)

Comment: This is good but requires to put ``color="custom-color"`` on all ion-nav tags.

Comment: The answer from @veljkoz below is the more convenient one.

Answer (score 7):

The navbar got its own styles. SO you need to overwrite it.

```
.toolbar-background {
  background-color: #0c60ee;
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer for this question.

Comment: This is working but is changing the toolbar's text color when I'm trying it.

Comment: What is the best place to put this?

Answer (score 4):

For Ionic 2 : [try this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/theming-your-app/)

in ionic 1 u can do in this way.
look here:[Ionic header](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#header)

other way

css :

```
.theme-color {
background-color: ##009688 !important;
color: #ffffff;}
```

html:

```
   <ion-nav-bar class="theme-color"><ion-nav-bar>
```

hope this helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

Right now (rc4) the correct way to do this is to change the `/src/themes/variables.scss` file, and add:

```
$toolbar-background: blue;
```

This effectively changes the color for wherever the value is used. More info [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/)

Comment: Actually, there are a lot of other properties for toolbar, i.e.  `$toolbar-background $toolbar-border-color  $toolbar-text-color $toolbar-active-color  $toolbar-inactive-color`

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<ion-navbar secondary *navbar>
```

There are some predefined variables in app.variables.scss in the app/theme directory:

```
 $colors: (
    primary:    #387ef5,
      secondary:  #32db64,
      danger:     #f53d3d,
      light:      #f4f4f4,
      dark:       #222,
      favorite:   #69BB7B
    );
```

I figured this from the following article: [A Guide to Styling an Ionic2 Application](http://www.joshmorony.com/a-guide-to-styling-an-ionic-2-application/).

Answer (score 1):

i find solution for the header by using color attribute as the following in nav bar :

```
<ion-header><ion-navbar color='primary'> ... </ion-navbar> </ion-header>
```

for the side menu toolbar background, go to variables.scss file and add this code :

```
$toolbar-background: $primary;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-nav-bar primary></ion-nav-bar>
```

Could also be secondary, etc, or other colors from the scss.

Comment: Thank you Dan, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this no longer appears to work in the latest version of Ionic2 (as of 10/25/16 - `ionic -version` = 2.1.4) with the following dependencies in package.json:

```
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.0.3",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
```

To solve, this I had to add the following to `app.scss`:

```
.toolbar-background {
  background-color: blue;
}
```